# How do I do WHERE clause on computed columns in Laravel eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to compute columns in Laravel according to other columns in a table, but I cannot do a WHERE on them since MySQL does't allow that.

I figured that I need a sub query. I am able to do that in MySQL like so:

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT
@inactive_percentage:=((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(APP_UPDATE_DATE))) / (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DEL_TASK_DUE_DATE) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(APP_UPDATE_DATE)) * 100 AS inactive_percentage,
IF(@inactive_percentage <= 33, "low", IF(@inactive_percentage >= 33 && @inactive_percentage <= 66, "normal", "high")) AS inactive

FROM APP_CACHE_VIEW
) as foo WHERE `inactive`='low'
```

but I don't know how to do the same in Laravel. I have some references online but they make no sense to me at all. How do I translate this to Eloquent code?

Answer (score 0):

Use DB::raw for your custom subquery.

```
$datas = DB::table( DB::raw('SELECT
@inactive_percentage:=((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(APP_UPDATE_DATE))) / (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DEL_TASK_DUE_DATE) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(APP_UPDATE_DATE)) * 100 AS inactive_percentage,
IF(@inactive_percentage <= 33, "low", IF(@inactive_percentage >= 33 && @inactive_percentage <= 66, "normal", "high")) AS inactive
FROM APP_CACHE_VIEW as foo') )->where('active','low')->get();

then 
foreach($datas as $data){
  //Your data processing / formatting
}
```

Comment: The SELECT statement inside the raw needs to be wrapped in `()` and still it says ` Syntax error or access violation: 1248 Every derived table must have its own alias`